# My Ruby Code doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby

```
num1, num2, num3 = gets
puts "Your first number = Your second number + Your third number. True or 
False?"
puts num1 == num2+num3
print "The sum is </> Your first number"
```

I want this program to accept 3 numbers from the user (which worked alright) and 
display the message saying that the 1st number is equal to the sum of the next 2 numbers, and if this is True or False, based on the user's input.
Why isn't this working? What is the solution to this mishap? Please let me know in the comments. Thank You! ☺

Comment: _I want this program to accept 3 numbers from the user (which worked alright)_ Are you sure? I don't think your parallel assignment works as you expect. And then there is no prompt for the user to answer your question. Also I'm not sure what `</>` is supposed to do? To be honest, it's clear that you're not entirely sure how this code works. Best bet is to do a tutorial then come back to this exercise/program.

Comment: maybe try `gets.split(" ")` and pass in an input like `1 2 3`. Also, to interpolate in a string you can use `print "the sum is #{num2 + num3}"`

Comment: This feels like a homework assignment that you haven't actually taken time to experiment with and understand yourself prior to asking here. I suggest you take @SagarPandya advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you wanted the user to type, but be aware that `gets` returns a single string, so perhaps you want to split it into pieces that are separated by white space:

```
num1, num2, num3 = gets.split(/\s+/)
```

So the user can now type

```
7 200 83
```

and those three items will end up in `num1`, `num2`, and `num3`. But also be aware that those are strings. So using the `+` operator will concatenate them:

```
num2 + num3  =>  "20083"
```

To add them as integers, you could do this:

```
num2.to_i + num3.to_i  =>  283
```

Comment: `scan(/\d+/)` probably makes more sense for numbers.

Comment: Yeah, although the original question would need to specify the expected input. It might not even be integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you should to get the numbers from **command line** you can do something like this:

```
# Get numbers
print 'Enter first number: '
num1 = gets.to_i
print 'Enter second number: '
num2 = gets.to_i
print 'Enter third number: '
num3 = gets.to_i

# Find result
sum = num2 + num3
result = 'more' if sum > num1
result = 'less' if sum < num1
result = 'equal' if sum == num1

# Show result with interpolation
puts "The sum is #{result} your first number"
```